# Scikit-Learn, Custom Transformer: ColumnSelectTransformer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Given data from

```
%%bash
mkdir data
wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/providers-train.csv -nc -P ./ml-data
wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/providers-metadata.csv -nc -P ./ml-data
```

I've been tasked to complete the following code snippets.

```
simple_cols = ['BEDCERT', 'RESTOT', 'INHOSP', 'CCRC_FACIL', 'SFF', 'CHOW_LAST_12MOS', 'SPRINKLER_STATUS', 'EXP_TOTAL', 'ADJ_TOTAL']

class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        return X[self.columns]

simple_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(simple_cols)),
])

assert data['RESTOT'].isnull().sum() > 0
assert not np.isnan(simple_features.fit_transform(data)).any()
```

to fulfil this assertion check

```
assert data['RESTOT'].isnull().sum() > 0
assert not np.isnan(simple_features.fit_transform(data)).any()
```

But I've not been able to pass the assertion test. Attached below is my attempt:

```
simple_cols = ['BEDCERT', 'RESTOT', 'INHOSP', 'CCRC_FACIL', 'SFF', 'CHOW_LAST_12MOS', 'SPRINKLER_STATUS', 'EXP_TOTAL', 'ADJ_TOTAL']

class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        X.dropna(inplace=True)
        return X[self.columns].values()

simple_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(simple_cols)),
])
```

Would appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in

```py
return X[self.columns].values()
```

The correct return statement should have been

```
return X[self.columns].values
```